# Execution plan different on same db in two instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, optimization, sql-execution-plan

I am struggling with a mysterious problem:
I have a query in production that dropped his performance dramatically, taking from a few second to two minutes.
By analyzing the execution plan, I found that it inexplicably no longer uses a non-clouster index on a field in the table.
I performed all the following steps:

- checked the index fragmentation:
- recompiled the index;
- dropped statistics;
- recreated the index;
- restarted the server;
  But nothing..
  Whenever i launch the query, the execution plan doesn't use the index.

If i force the query to use the index (with a query hint) it is done istantly.
Why sql server does not consider the index in execution plan?

To try to recreate the problem, I restored the same db in another instance of sql server:
the result is that the execution plan use index by default.

Why in production still not using the index?
(HW configuration is very good, the server license is standard edition)

The query is:

```
 SELECT Anagrafiche.[Ragione Sociale], Anagrafiche.IDAnagrafica
 FROM ([Registrazioni Magazzino]
 INNER JOIN Anagrafiche ON [Registrazioni Magazzino].IDCliente = Anagrafiche.IDAnagrafica) 
 INNER JOIN Movimenti ON [Registrazioni Magazzino].RifIDMovimenti = Movimenti.ID
 GROUP BY Anagrafiche.[Ragione Sociale], Anagrafiche.IDAnagrafica, Anagrafiche.Fornitore
 HAVING (((Anagrafiche.Fornitore)=1))
 ORDER BY Anagrafiche.[Ragione Sociale]
```

The right exec plan is:
[Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4HYl.png)

[right plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WMO-jaxzHO-CgG_iC1iG2N0A6jrBPXDu/view?usp=sharing)

The wrong is:
[Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNgzG.png)

[wrong plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IHB3kCKoQFRnx2a9huElHXRZ0j2w17m8/view?usp=sharing)

The table [registrazioni magazzino] contains about 980.000 rows. The field is [idcliente], the index is [IX_Registrazioni Magazzino_2]

Comment: You'd have to share the actual execution plan for anyone to guess.  And have you enabled the Query Store? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Same `@@options`? Some `@@options` values are plan-affecting. [PasteThePlan(s)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: I've put the both execution plans.. is it enough?

Comment: I've enabled the query store now, but the right plan is not present in the plans list. how can i do?

Comment: screen grabs of plans is no good, see the link in the earlier comment to PasteThePlan

Answer (score 0):

**The non-clustered index on `[Registrazioni Magazzino]` is not a *covering index***, in other words: there are columns which still need to be gotten out of the clustered index via a key lookup.

Therefore the compiler needs to make a decision based on statistics as to whether to use the index and do key lookups; or whether, given the number of rows, the cost of those extra key lookups is not worth it and a scan of the clustered index should be done instead.

**This is compounded** by the fact that, since no columns are actually selected out of `[Registrazioni Magazzino]`, the query has been transformed to an `EXISTS` query, which is how it should have been written in the first place. A row-goal/`TOP` of 1 is placed on the inner side of the join, so the compiler thinks it's going to get results quickly and ignores the large cost of doing so many scans.

**The solution here is very simple: change the non-clustered index to include the `RifIDMovimenti` column.** You could do this as a second key-column, but I think an `INCLUDE` column would be better:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Registrazioni Magazzino] ON [Registrazioni Magazzino]
  (IDCliente) INCLUDE (RifIDMovimenti)
  WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON);
```

An index on `Anagrafiche (Fornitore, [Ragione Sociale]) INCLUDE (IDAnagrafica)` would help also. This means that `Fornitore` can be pre-filtered, and the Sort will be removed from the query.

---

**Further notes about your query:**

- You should use aliases, especially when you have table names with spaces (which you should avoid anyway)
- As mentioned, this should really be an `EXISTS` query, without a `GROUP BY`
- Simple non-aggregated filters should be placed in `WHERE` not `HAVING`
- There is no need to bracket joins, and it does not help or change what the compiler does

These changes are not essential, but would help with query comprehension, and may help the optimizer also.

So your query would ideally become this:

```sql
SELECT a.[Ragione Sociale], a.IDAnagrafica
 FROM  Anagrafiche a
 WHERE a.Fornitore = 1
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
      FROM [Registrazioni Magazzino] r
      INNER JOIN Movimenti m ON r.RifIDMovimenti = m.ID
      WHERE r.IDCliente = a.IDAnagrafica)
 ORDER BY a.[Ragione Sociale];
```

Comment: Hi! first of all, thank you so much for the prompt reply

Comment: Unfortunately, the query is inside an old application that i can't modify.. So i can only make changes by the db side.

Comment: I tried to insert the cover index, and the second index on the table "anagrafiche".
But the result execution plan on original query is the same. The index is not used.
With your recommended query it is used instead

Comment: But I still don't understand why the same database, copied to another sql instance, uses the uncovered index by default and not a table scan.

Comment: Probably a fine balance, and the server keeps switching between the two every time something changes. Can you share the new query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Update: following your reccomandation i created another index with the two key:

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Registrazioni Magazzino_2b] ON [dbo].[Registrazioni 
    Magazzino]
    (
 [IDCliente] ASC,
 [RifIDMovimenti] ASC
    )

and now the query use the index:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyqKIlsUd

Comment: What happens if you run sp_updatestats on both instances? (assuming you can do so without performance impact - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52408/whats-the-impact-of-running-sp-updatestats-in-production-server)

Comment: Now, i've runned it in production:
- update statistics;
- re-run the query with option recompile;
And now use the right index! good

Comment: curiosity: why the execution plan did not suggest the index with two keys?

Comment: Missing plan is often not accurate, more useful as a hint that something should be done. Look at the query and check for key lookups, sorts and hash joins. These are the ones you need to try to remove. https://use-the-index-luke.com/ and https://www.brentozar.com/archive/category/how-to-think-like-the-sql-server-engine/ are good resources

Comment: Thank you for resolution and for shared resource. I will analyze them in depth